# Project Structure Change in Eclipse for JSP (Java Server Pages)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have recently installed Eclipse and Tomcat for developing Some Web Projects using JSP.

When I see some tutorials then their project structure was different but now it is completely changed. so I am confused that where to write Java Code and where to write JSP Code and HTML Code ?

**OLD Project Structure**

[image]

**NEW**

[image]

Comment: Are you learning independently or as part of a course with specific requirements?

Comment: Looks like you’ve switched to maven. That is important as it has pretty strong opinions

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen in latest eclipse creates folder structure like maven with some difference `src\main\resources` is not created by default so `src\main\java` must be used for that. also test folders not generated.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Maven does not _require_ those folders to be present.  Apparently the Eclipse wizard does not create all of them.  It still looks very much like a Maven layout.  Also, putting resources in src/main/java will not work when compiling from the command line.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes command line wont copy but when you create a war using eclipse it copies non java files as it is to the `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Unfortunately that makes it hard to use in an automated build environment.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I agree. Maven or Gradle is way to go, but the question is about Eclipse.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Because OP is confused.  Saying to put non-Java files in the Java folder is simply bad advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of tutorials are outdated and used older version of Eclipse.

Basically, in a java web application the final output either war or a folder should be as follows.

```
/ (Web resources like html, jsp, js and css files)
|
+--WEB-INF/
|   |
|   +--web.xml (optional since servlet 3.0)
|   +--classes/ (will have the compiled java classes and class path resources)
|   +--lib/ (third party libraries)
+--META-INF/ (will have manifest file)
```

Eclipse changed the folder structure to be on par with other build tools like Maven and Gradle.

In the new structure

1. `src/main/java` will consists of java sources and other class-path resources like XMLs and other configuration files.
2. `src/main/webapp` will have all web resources.

When you build the app eclipse compiles the java classes from `src/main/java` folder and put the class files in the `WEB-INF/classes` also copies non java class-path resources as it is to `WEB-INF/classes`. And the files in `src/main/webapp` will be copied to the root(`/`) folder as it is.

**Off-Topic:** I will advise you to use a build tool like Maven or Gradle so your project will work in any IDE and environment.

Answer (score 0):

`.java` files go under `src/main/java`, JSPs under `src/main/webapp`. If you want the old paths, use the text fields given to you when creating the project as you go through the wizard pages.